# Sharepoint: Limit search results by field

Tags: sharepoint, search, sharepoint-2007

I have setup a search scope for the current members of a website (a "Phone book" type of search). It is setup to automatically suggest limiting search results by people's jobtitles, adding something like "jobtitle:Manager" to the search query.

For single words ("Manager", "Supervisor", etc.) this works fine, but as soon as the title contains more than one word ("Managing Supervisor"), it returns zero search results. My gut feeling is that it's because when the url is entered as `jobtitle:Managing Supervisor`, it limits results by jobtitle = Managing, and then `Supervisor` simply becomes a generic search term.

I tried testing with manually added quotation marks, `jobtitle:"Supervising Manager"`, but they are removed when I land on the search page and the effects are the same.

Is there any way to allow limiting of search results by fields with multiple words?

This is running SharePoint 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a `+` between the words?

Comment: It makes no difference, although the "+" stays in the search field.